# How to create a graph from an adjacency matrix by also specifying nodes coordinates in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following R code:

```
library('igraph')

nodes <- c('a','b','c','d')
x <- c(0,1,2,3)
y <- c(0,1,2,3)

from <- c('a','b','c')
to <- c('b','c','d')

NodeList <- data.frame(nodes, x ,y)
EdgeList <- data.frame(from, to)

plot(graph_from_data_frame(vertices = NodeList, d= EdgeList, directed = FALSE))
```

Which emits the graph I want. However I need to be able to use the adjacency matrix instead of `from` and `to` vectors. Function `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` does not include a parameter to specify the coordinates of nodes. How to achieve this?

Comment: load in the graph using graph_from_adjacency_matrix and then set the vertex attributes; `vertex_attr`

Comment: ... but if this is only for plotting then you could just use the `layout` argument; `plot(g, layout=as.matrix(NodeList[-1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As @user20650 mentioned above], you can specify the coordinates of the vertices latter, using `vertex_attr()`:

```
library('igraph')

adjm <- matrix(
  c(0, rep(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), times = 3)), 4, , F, list(letters[1:4], letters[1:4])
  )

g01 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, 'undirected') -> g02

vertex_attr(g02, name = 'x') <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
vertex_attr(g02, name = 'y') <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)

par(mfrow = 1:2)

plot(g01)
plot(g02)
```

[image: vertex_attr]